# Create document from template in javascript on a modern sharepoint site

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts, modern-pages

Does anyone know of an equivalent to the createNewDocumentWithProgID() or createNewDocumentWithRedirect2() JavaScript function that will work on a modern spfx SharePoint site?

Answer (score 0):

No but you can do it the conventional way but it requires bypassing SPContext by putting vars in a list and calling them into the application. I use in this context - I have a SPFx List Command Set Extension that calls a list on the local site called Document Wizard - The list contains a path to the template - default naming convention of the file etc - the webpart handles the save location based on the library it is run from. This allows me to pass the correct required vars to the old createNewDocument commands and display a button with a dynamic list of templates available for the team to use. My create document script I can share with you it takes the vars - creates the document - then opens the item edit form for the user to change any metadata - when the form is closed the document will open for editing in a new browser tab

Comment: This does require linking of some old SP scripts but I manage to call those in the Create document script and not inside the extension itself